# In angularJS store the admin(id, password) by start from a json in localstorage, but angularJS didn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I want in angularJS store oder preload the admin(id, password) by start from a json in localstorage, but angularJS return always error. the init function I have written through a ng-controller="initAdminController" in a div.

I want to know, where is the error exactly, in script.js or in index.html and how can i fix it.

skript.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('store', []);

    app.controller('initAdminController', function($userFactory){

    admin.id=0;
    admin.name="admin";
    admin.password="admin";

    userFactory.put(admin);
    });

    app.factory('userFactory', function(){

    return{
    get: function (userinfo) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(userinfo) || '[]');
    },

    put: function(userinfo){
    console('adminInit wird aufgerufen');
    localStorage.setItem('user' + userinfo.id, JSON.stringify(userinfo));

    }
    };
    });
```

and the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Angular Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/mobile-angular-ui-base.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/mobile-angular-ui-hover.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/mobile-angular-ui-desktop.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="store" >  


    <div id="pageContent" data-role="page" >    
    <div data-role="header" class="site-header" >
      <h1>logIn</h1>
    </div>

    <p>Willkommen: <span>{{user.name}}</span> </p>
     <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <form method="get" role="form" name="Loginform">
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="text" name="userID" ng-model='user.name' required    placeholder="user ID">
            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required     placeholder="password">
          </div>
            <input type="submit" ng-disabled="Loginform.$invalid" value="submit"     ng-click:login() />

        </form>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" id="footer" class="site-footer">
      <h1>footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="initAdminController"></div>

    <!-- load the libs   -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular-loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/directive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filters/filter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the error:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $userFactoryProvider <- $userFactory ........

Answer (score 0):

It's a small issue of you using "$userFactory"  instead of using "userFactory" to inject.

Comment: thank you, the script run now, the error was console()
truly is console.log()

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to inject your userFactory into the controller:

```
app.controller('initAdminController', ['userFactory', function(userFactory){ ... }]);
```

Please note that $ sign is reserved for angularjs properties and such. The $$ is reserverd for private properties in angularjs that you should not use.